# position div to bottom right

Tags: css, css-float

I am creating facebook like chat in my website.So whenever user clicks to chat to someone the chat window should open in the bottom right corner.The next window should be left to the other opened chat windows.Also the chat windows should not occupy extra height on page.They should just be placed at a higher z-index to overlap the page content behind them.I am not that good in css,please help.following is the code which I am using,but it's not working properly

```
.chat{
    z-index:50;
    width: 300px;
    height:300px;
    margin-left:10px;
    float:right;
    border:1px solid blue;
}
```

I am getting this ,it's adding scroll bar to page and not going to very right.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to have a parent element ( a div ) with :

```
.parent { position: fixed; bottom: 0; left: 0; right:0; width: 100%; }
```

you need fixed position so that the bar remains at the bottom of the browser, not of your page. that acts like a container for your chat divs, which should have

```
.chat { float: right; position: relative; }
```

so they can act as containers to their actual chat

here's a fiddle with a couple of chat windows :

http://jsfiddle.net/SXZKe/1/

**Edit:** Added the fiddle

Comment: you need to keep the boxes to equal height with JS. Depends on what requirements you have other than that. An example would be to have a fixed height for `.text` and `overflow:auto` to have a scrollbar when/if you exceed that.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the float: right, adding position: fixed, right : 0%, and bottom: 0%;

Comment: this works well but all chat windows are overlapping ,thus only the last opened window is visible.how to fix this

Answer (score 0):

Use bottom css property for that:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_bottom.asp